# Dictionary class in C# - Equality of two object

Tags: c#, dictionary, equals

I have a class named Class1
I override its Equals function
Now I have an instance of Dictionary
And I added an instance of Class1 named OBJ1 to it.
I have another instance of Class1 named OBJ2.
the code returns true for OBJ1.Equals(OBJ2).
But I can't find OBJ2 in dictionary.

Here is pseudo code

```
Class1 OBJ1 = new Class1(x, y, z);
Class1 OBJ2 = new Class1(a, b, c);
Dictionary<Class1, int> dic1 = new Dictionary<Class1, int>();
dic1.Add(OBJ1, 3);
OBJ1.Equals(OBJ2) -------------> return true
Dictionary.ContainsKey(OBJ2) --------------> return false
```

why is this happening?
any help would be highly welcomed

Comment: Did you override GetHashcode for your class as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make certain Class1 overrides GetHashCode().  The return from that method is the first thing checked when comparing equality.  The default implementation is unique for each object.

Answer (score 13):

2 possibilities:

1. `GetHashCode` has not been overridden correctly. You might want to take a look at [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overriden in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c)
2. `OBJ1` has been mutated after it has been added to the dictionary in a way that impacts its hashcode. In this case,  the bucket it is placed in will no longer be correct - `ContainsKey` will end up hunting for it in a different bucket.

From [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> As long as an object is used as a key
>   in the Dictionary, it
>   must not change in any way that
>   affects its hash value.

Answer (score 12):

Chances are you haven't overridden `GetHashCode` in a manner consistent with `Equals`.

The contract of `GetHashCode` requires that if `OBJ1.Equals(OBJ2)` returns true, then `OBJ1.GetHashCode()` must return the same value as `OBJ2.GetHashCode()`.

IIRC, you'll get a compiler error (or at least a warning) if you override `Equals` without overriding `GetHashCode()`.

Another possibility is that you haven't actually `overridden` `Equals`, but *overloaded* it by adding a new signature, e.g.

```
public bool Equals(Class1 other)
```

In general, to provide a "natural" value equality comparison you should:

- Override Equals(object)
- Override GetHashCode
- Strongly consider implementing `IEquatable<T>`
- Consider overloading == and !=

Answer (score 4):

You probably did not override GetHashcode in your class. When you override Equals you must override GetHashcode as well, else Dictionary won't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you override GetHashCode as well ?
Can you display the implementation of the Equals method ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you override the `GetHashCode` either?

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `GetHashCode` as well, but also don't forget that you may need to pass in a custom Comparer to the Dictionary constructor as well [as pointed out in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632768/custom-class-used-as-key-in-dictionary-but-key-not-found)