# Custom Class as key for Dictionary in C# not working

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash, equality

I recently started studying C# but am stuck on this particular case. Yes I have gone over the previous questions but was not able to get what the issue in my code is.
[Custom Class used as key in Dictionary but key not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632768/custom-class-used-as-key-in-dictionary-but-key-not-found)
This is the closest one I could find, but the answer given here does not seem to work for me.

I have a Dictionary registry<Customers, string>.
Customers is a class that has 2 strings: s1 and s2. A customer can match either s1 or s2 (both are not required).

Class Customers:

```
public class Customers
    {
        public string _s1;
        public string _s2;

        public Customers(string s1, string s2)
        {
            _s1 = s1;
            _s2 = s2;
        }

        public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Customers>
        {
            public bool Equals(Customers x, Customers y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inside Equals");
                return ((x._s1.Equals(y._s1)) || (x._s2.Equals(y._s2)));
            }
            public int GetHashCode(Customers x)
            {
                return x._s1.GetHashCode() ^ x._s2.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
Dictionary<Customers, string> registry = new Dictionary<Customers, string>(new Customers.EqualityComparer());

Customers key = new Customers("1", "2");
Customers key2 = new Customers("12", "21");
registry.Add(key, "12");
registry.Add(key2, "22");
Customers lookUp1 = new Customers("1", "2");
Customers lookUp2 = new Customers("1", "32");
if (registry.ContainsKey(lookUp2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
}
```

The issue is that when both s1 and s2 are matching, then I get "Found", but when only one of them does I get "Not found" despite having changed Equals() accordingly and giving the reference of the new EqualityComparer in the Constructor as well.

Also, For lookup1 I do get "Inside Equals" but not for lookup2 and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `Dictionary` is basically a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class is implemented as a **hash table**.

and first rule for matching is that hashcodes should be equal and `"1".GetHashCode() ^ "2".GetHashCode()` (for `key`) will definitely differ from `"1".GetHashCode() ^ "32".GetHashCode()`(for `lookUp2`).

Comment: Thank you! that does seem to be the issue. I changed the return x._s1.GetHashCode() ^ x._s2.GetHashCode(); to return 0 and it seems to work.
But I read that this could result in a not so efficient code?

Comment: @Sanju I can't think of implementation for `GetHashcode` supporting "or" logic from top of my head. I would suggest just using simple `Dictionary<string, string>` with multiple keys referring to the same value.

Comment: The problem is *deeper*: even when we put `public int GetHashCode(Customers x) => 0;` - awful but *correct* implementation the dictionary will not work properly. The basic equality design is incorrect.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes, there are multiple problems with the code/approach.

Answer (score 10):

You have a problem with **equality** *design*. Each equality correspondence **must follow** these rules:

1. `A.Equals(A) == true` for all `A`.
2. if `A.Equals(B) == true` then `B.Equals(A) == true` for all `A, B`.
3. if `A.Equals(B) && B.Equals(C) == true` then `A.Equals(C) == true` for all `A, B, C`.

As we can see, the rule #3 (transitive rule) is *broken*:

```
   Customer A = new Customer("x", "y");
   Customer B = new Customer("x", "z");
   Customer C = new Customer("p", "z");
```

Since equality is implemented *incorrectly*, `Dictionary<K, V>` doesn't work *properly*.